# Poi - how to read contents from multiple files efficiently

Tags: java-8, apache-poi

I'm using the following code to load an excel from the computer.

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
CreationHelper crateHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = crateHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

It takes about 200ms to do this.

And closing it takes about 100ms.

```
workbook.close();
```

Now I'd like to read from more than 3000 files. So it'll take too much time.
**Why does opening/closing an excel take so much time?**
Is there any way I could use to **improve the loading/closing performance**?

Comment: Use multiple threads, and split the files up between the threads?

Comment: Though multiple threads double the speed, I still want to improve more.

Comment: Then add more threads or a bigger machine!